# Sub routine reference is not working

Tags: perl

I am learning subroutine reference. I written a code but it is not working

```
use strict;
use warnings;
sub test1 {
#$arg = shift;
print "arg";
}

sub test2 {
return \&test1;
}

&test2;
```

Output is nothing. Any thoughts why my code is not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`&test2` does almost the same as `test2()`. It runs test2, which returns the reference to test1, but does not run it. You have to dereference the reference to call the referenced code:

```
test2->();
```

Or even

```
test2()->();
```

Comment: Just a small query. What we say to  "->" operator

Comment: @Nitesh: "dereference", as in C or C++.

Answer (score 3):

First of all,

```
&test2;
```

is a poor way of calling a subroutine. Don't use `&` if you don't even know what it does! That should be

```
test2;
```

or

```
test2();
```

---

On to your problem: You never call the returned subroutine!

```
test2()->();
```

Answer (score 1):

You're returning a reference to a subroutine. You need to dereference to actually call it:

```
&{test2()}
```